# Click on hyperlink on IE from ExcelVBA

Tags: vba, internet-explorer, macros

This is the HTML code for a hyperlink, basically only gives me class name and href:

```html
<TD class=npcFirstColumn noWrap>
  <A href="QEI_QEX_ISSUE_SIGNOFF_MAIN.aspx?ParId=0000000000000000000216231&amp;HdrId=0000000000000000000216231&amp;ItmId=0000000000000000000216231&amp;Path=&amp;RefCtl=&amp;Navaction=&amp;USER_TREE_FOR=ISSUE_DETAIL">ISS0012898</A> </TD>
```

I need either to be able to click on this hyperlink OR copy the href file as a string to my browser. 
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this, I'm assuming you already have Internet Explorer opened up and on the page of interest.

```
ie.document.getelementsbyClassName("npcFirstColumn")(0).getElementsByTagName("a")(0).click
```

Comment: unfortunately that does not work :( it will not click the link

Comment: Sounds like you'll need to iterate each collection. It may not be the first element (0) in the collection.

Comment: If you want additional help, you should include your full code and the url of interest, if possible